# FlxG.overlap doesen't work correctly when changing angle of an object

Tags: overlap, haxe, angle, haxeflixel

FlxG.overlap won't work correctly when I change the angle of an object.
The object's hitbox is still where it would have been if it wasn't angled.
I don't know how to fix that.

I tried updating the sprite's hitbox and changing the angle before adding the sprite, yet the sprite's hitbox stayed as its angle would have been 0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`FlxG.overlap` uses a simple bounding box test (AABB) to check for overlap and ignores rotation.

If you want to test for overlap of rotated sprites, then you can use [FlxG.pixelPerfectOverlap](https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxG.html#pixelPerfectOverlap). But it can be much slower that `overlap`, so be a little careful. It tests the actual pixels of each sprite, so can also be used for odd shaped graphics that use alpha.